Waiting girl's face
In June 2023, at Xenium Party 2023, a 4KB intro created by Wacek, Luke, and Jammer for the Commodore 64 was presented, featuring the face of a waiting girl.
The task is to write the shortest possible program that draws a girl's face before what she is waiting for happens.

The image below should be clearly visible, but the color choice for the dark background and light pixels is optional.

The pixels positions you can get from below unoptimized snippet


pixels=
[65,0,68,0,70,0,72,0,74,0,56,1,59,1,61,1,63,1,65,1,67,1,68,1,70,1,71,1,73,1,74,1,75,1,64,2,67,2,69,2,70,
2,72,2,74,2,60,3,63,3,65,3,67,3,69,3,71,3,72,3,73,3,75,3,76,3,57,4,62,4,66,4,68,4,70,4,72,4,74,4,75,4,60,
5,63,5,65,5,67,5,69,5,70,5,71,5,73,5,74,5,76,5,77,5,62,6,64,6,66,6,68,6,70,6,72,6,73,6,75,6,76,6,59,7,61,
7,64,7,67,7,69,7,71,7,72,7,74,7,76,7,77,7,63,8,66,8,68,8,70,8,71,8,73,8,74,8,75,8,77,8,60,9,62,9,64,9,66,
9,68,9,70,9,72,9,74,9,76,9,77,9,78,9,70,10,72,10,73,10,75,10,76,10,78,10,63,11,67,11,69,11,72,11,74,11,75,
11,77,11,78,11,65,12,74,12,76,12,78,12,79,12,64,13,67,13,69,13,73,13,75,13,77,13,79,13,62,14,66,14,71,14,
74,14,75,14,76,14,77,14,78,14,65,15,69,15,73,15,75,15,77,15,79,15,81,15,59,16,62,16,64,16,66,16,68,16,72,
16,74,16,76,16,77,16,78,16,61,17,64,17,66,17,69,17,71,17,73,17,75,17,76,17,78,17,57,18,60,18,62,18,64,18,
66,18,68,18,71,18,73,18,75,18,77,18,78,18,80,18,59,19,61,19,63,19,65,19,68,19,70,19,71,19,73,19,75,19,77,
19,58,20,60,20,62,20,64,20,66,20,68,20,70,20,72,20,74,20,76,20,78,20,79,20,57,21,59,21,61,21,63,21,65,21,
68,21,70,21,72,21,73,21,75,21,77,21,78,21,55,22,59,22,61,22,63,22,66,22,70,22,78,22,57,23,59,23,61,23,62,
23,64,23,67,23,69,23,72,23,74,23,77,23,78,23,79,23,55,24,58,24,63,24,79,24,57,25,60,25,63,25,65,25,69,25,
78,25,79,25,56,26,62,26,64,26,67,26,79,26,64,27,65,27,79,27,80,27,54,28,65,28,66,28,80,28,65,29,66,29,80,
29,81,29,66,30,80,30,82,30,64,31,66,31,67,31,81,31,82,31,66,32,68,32,82,32,83,32,65,33,67,33,83,33,84,33,
63,34,66,34,67,34,68,34,84,34,66,35,84,35,85,35,65,36,67,36,68,36,88,38,90,39,92,41,94,41,94,42,96,42,67,
43,95,43,63,44,68,44,96,44,98,44,65,45,67,45,98,45,100,45,69,46,63,47,65,47,67,47,101,47,54,48,68,48,70,
48,74,48,103,48,57,49,60,49,63,49,65,49,67,49,105,49,61,50,66,50,69,50,71,50,106,50,107,50,56,51,59,51,63,
51,65,51,68,51,76,51,108,51,61,52,63,52,66,52,69,52,71,52,73,52,109,52,110,52,57,53,60,53,65,53,67,53,70,
53,110,53,111,53,61,54,63,54,65,54,68,54,72,54,75,54,110,54,111,54,58,55,64,55,67,55,69,55,71,55,73,55,
111,55,112,55,63,56,65,56,67,56,70,56,74,56,112,56,62,57,66,57,69,57,71,57,73,57,77,57,112,57,113,57,65,
58,68,58,72,58,75,58,108,58,112,58,64,59,67,59,69,59,71,59,74,59,110,59,112,59,113,59,62,60,66,60,70,60,
73,60,77,60,112,60,69,61,72,61,75,61,106,61,111,61,64,62,66,62,68,62,70,62,72,62,74,62,77,62,103,62,105,
62,108,62,110,62,111,62,75,63,102,63,110,63,70,64,72,64,74,64,78,64,101,64,76,65,100,65,108,65,109,65,70,
66,72,66,74,66,78,66,99,66,108,66,76,67,79,67,99,67,107,67,71,68,75,68,98,68,106,68,107,68,73,69,78,69,98,
69,105,69,76,70,82,70,97,70,102,70,104,70,70,71,79,71,96,71,103,71,72,72,75,72,102,72,103,72,77,73,80,73,
96,73,102,73,84,74,102,74,103,74,74,75,81,75,103,75,104,75,76,76,79,76,104,76,83,77,103,77,104,77,73,78,
102,78,104,78,105,78,79,79,105,79,88,80,92,80,95,80,101,80,104,80,106,80,84,81,98,81,105,81,107,81,108,
81,103,82,107,82,109,82,86,83,90,83,95,83,101,83,108,83,109,83,110,83,92,84,105,84,108,84,110,84,111,84,
97,85,107,85,109,85,110,85,72,86,89,86,107,86,109,86,110,86,74,87,93,87,99,87,107,87,108,87,110,87,106,
88,107,88,109,88,80,89,105,89,106,89,108,89,109,89,105,90,107,90,109,90,104,91,106,91,107,91,108,91,109,
91,103,92,104,92,106,92,107,92,102,93,103,93,105,93,102,94,104,94,102,95,100,96,103,96,80,97,101,97,102,
97,95,98,104,98,97,99,99,99,106,99,108,99,109,99,94,100,101,100,105,100,106,100,108,100,110,100,97,101,
103,101,105,101,107,101,108,101,110,101,111,101,107,102,109,102,110,102,111,102,94,103,102,103,109,103,
111,103,112,103,107,104,110,104,112,104,113,104,104,105,108,105,110,105,111,105,112,105,111,106,112,106,
113,106,107,107,110,107,112,107,109,108,111,108,112,108,108,109,110,109,111,109,102,110,105,110,107,110,
109,110,104,111,107,111,101,112,106,112,107,112,84,113,95,113,103,113,105,113,106,113,97,114,102,114,105,
114,107,114,99,115,104,115,105,115,106,115,102,116,105,116,107,116,97,117,103,117,105,117,107,117,100,
118,104,118,106,118,107,118,108,118,103,119,106,119,108,119,102,120,104,120,105,120,107,120,108,120,109,
120,107,121,109,121,104,122,106,122,108,122,109,122,110,122,102,123,107,123,109,123,110,123,111,123,106,
124,109,124,111,124,104,125,107,125,109,125,110,125,111,125,96,126,108,126,110,126,111,126,98,127,106,127,
109,127,111,127,112,127,102,128,108,128,110,128,111,128,112,128,108,129,110,129,112,129,104,130,109,130,
110,130,111,130,112,130,106,131,108,131,111,131,109,132,110,132,111,132,112,132,105,133,107,133,109,133,
111,133,112,133,109,134,111,134,106,135,108,135,109,135,110,135,111,135,105,136,108,136,48,137,60,137,
100,137,103,137,107,137,109,137,106,138,108,138,109,138,87,139,90,139,102,139,105,139,107,139,70,140,74,
140,77,140,104,140,106,140,93,141,103,141,80,142,87,142,89,142,91,142,72,143,76,143,82,143,36,145,52,145,
59,145,64,145,54,146,61,147,58,148,56,149,54,150,39,152,44,152,48,152,53,152,51,153,49,154,42,155,46,155,
48,156,44,157,47,157,40,158,46,158,44,159,42,160,45,160,38,161,44,161,41,162,43,162,39,164,41,164,43,164,
42,165,24,166,39,166,41,166,26,167,41,167,40,168,38,169,40,169,35,170,40,170,37,171,39,171,30,172,38,172,
34,173,36,173,38,173,32,174,37,174,36,175,34,176,37,176,28,177,31,177,35,177,34,178,36,178,32,179,35,179,
30,180,34,180,33,181,30,182,32,182,33,183,29,184,8,185,32,185,26,186,28,186,23,187,27,188,29,188,25,189,
29,189,0,190,28,190,2,191,23,191,26,191,28,191,27,192,4,193,23,193,25,193,27,193,26,194,22,195,25,195,24,
196,23,197,25,197,23,199]

putPixel = function(x, y, R, G, B, A) {
  if (!putPixel.ctx) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    c.width = window.innerWidth;
    c.height = window.innerHeight;
    document.body.appendChild(c);
    putPixel.ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  }
  var d = putPixel.ctx.createImageData(1, 1);
  d.data[0] = R;
  d.data[1] = G;
  d.data[2] = B;
  d.data[3] = A;
  putPixel.ctx.putImageData(d, x, y);
};

for (var i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 2) {
  var x = pixels[i];
  var y = pixels[i + 1];
  putPixel(x, y, 255, 255, 0, 255);
}
body {
  background: black;
}



Leaderboard:


/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 275787; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 88163; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    else console.log(body);
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() > b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() < b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
body {
  text-align: left !important;
  display: block !important;
}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/all.css?v=ffb5d0584c5f">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




You should probably write a clearer spec on what exactly is allowed regarding resolution, image size, specific colouring, what the ascii-art tag means etc (and provide a pure copy of this image outside of the stack snippet)

Related (also a demoscene screen)

Does the thing the girl is waiting for have to happen within the program? Are the requirements met by a program which displays a static image, if what she is waiting for will never happen? Perhaps somebody should write an answer in Godot.

At the risk of sucking the fun out of it, would someone care to explain what "waiting" and "before what the girl is waiting for happens" mean?  I have no idea what's going on.

@DonHatch A kiss, probably

Is ASCII art an acceptable output format? I think we have a consensus on Meta saying it is. If so, then which character(s) may we use?

@Shaggy I think that in this matter, a consensus should also be sought or reached on Meta.

HTML, 920 910 bytes


<img src=data:;base64,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



Compressed with cwebp -z 9:
Dimension: 114 x 200
Output:    666 bytes (0.23 bpp)
Lossless-ARGB compressed size: 666 bytes

Header size: 61 bytes, image data size: 579
Lossless features used: PALETTE
Precision Bits: histogram=3 transform=3 cache=0
Palette size:   2


Would a transparent background save you any bytes?

I'll check it out.

JavaScript (ES6), 975 bytes
-9 bytes thanks to Daniël van den Berg
This encodes the 64 custom tiles of 8x8 pixels used in the original C64 version and the grid of 25 rows and 15 columns filled with these tiles.
Everything is stored into a single array of 15*25 + 64*8 = 887 bytes, encoded in base64 and compressed by shortening runs of consecutive A's.


s=atob(`(ECAw.QFBgc-gJCgs-wN 4.PABAR-S!EEw)BQVFg!BcY)ZGg!Bsc*HR4AHy,ISIAIyQ+EQQlJico+CM Ck,CMAKisY/Cwt,QALi8/ETAx/DIz&IwQANBE1BDY%QABDcj-4OQ,EQA6/Ds8.BD0+ESMAPiM+B!Pw/'pABACE oEhqpKpRqlWkFTsVbjXbbdYAQ&FJVAKIIpBGIu9VttFCo8qg QEBAwIBCiCASKBQqKKoVZRVSlVKEqXUaqqrVa0BlAEBBQADAQEDEkgE E"CiiUMGBgQNAIDAgYEDBQYUChyEGg"wYED-QQ"IEIogCo QUCFF gAFIgCSASIAQQCqQSpIoSqQR JACgEkCgIIMEC)EDAwYqkUikEYBUABGKJBKJJJUg B"QSgEEDAQNBAIDARVAFUAiCEABAQABAgABEAKAQCAgEBAIBADAQCAwCAUCJI EE C!BEAIAi!gAE'wEDBgQGDQhE!RQ IgIIQAIIAC gFGiiwEigoG#BAwEBAbDYqPQ2CwUBQIACKIEI ECAQTQWGqggSBEACCAQKkkDQcOBQYD C ggg h DAaKRwpKnRS7aDUoZCkQJ"EDAgMDBkFAhFCAqIDQBwUHAgcGAgM#kQ R"BIAgCoASKLQKRQC"IAGAEAQBAEI B QARAhCAIAQQCAQCQQSgAKhAKC!IIABUIRABAUEAgEB CQIlAkEQgFCI UAKgiEBSICoQCQQK I`.replace(/\W/g,c=>"A".repeat(c[C="charCodeAt"]()-30)));document.write`<canvas id=c height=200>`;c=c.getContext`2d`;for(y=200;y--;)for(x=120;x--;)c.fillRect(x,y,1,1,c.fillStyle=s[C](375+s[C]((y>>3)*15+x/8)*8+y%8)>>x%8&1?"#FF0":"#000")



Encoder
"use strict";

// turn the data provided in the challenge into a list of [x,y] coordinates
let DATA = getData(),
    coord = [];

for(let n = 0; n < DATA.length; n += 2) {
  coord.push([ DATA[n], DATA[n + 1] ]);
}

// extract all the tiles
let tile = [];

coord.forEach(([x, y]) => {
  // the coordinates provided in the challenge are not aligned with the grid
  // we have to shift x by 2 pixels
  x += 2;

  let X = x >> 3,
      Y = y >> 3;

  tile[Y] = tile[Y] || [...Array(15)].map(_ => [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]);
  tile[Y][X][y & 7] |= 1 << (x & 7);
});

// save the distinct tiles into tileMap and turn tile[] into
// the tile grid, filled with tile indices in tileMap
let tileMap = new Map,
    id = 0;

tile.forEach((c, y) => {
  c.forEach((a, x) => {
    let key = a.map(v => v.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join("");

    if(!tileMap.has(key)) {
      tileMap.set(key, id++);
    }
    tile[y][x] = tileMap.get(key);
  });
});

// convert the keys of tileMap into an array of bytes
let tileData = [...tileMap].map(a => a[0]).join("").match(/../g).map(s => parseInt(s, 16));

// put the grid and the tile data into a single array of bytes
let bytes = [ ...tile.flat(), ...tileData ]

// convert it to base64
let base64 = Buffer.from(bytes).toString("base64").replace(/=/g, "");

// compress by replacing sequences of A's with characters in the range [32..47]
let packed = base64.replace(/A{2,17}/g, s => String.fromCharCode(32 + s.length - 2));

console.log(packed);

function getData() {
  return [
    65,0,68,0,70,0,72,0,74,0,56,1,59,1,61,1,63,1,65,1,67,1,68,1,70,1,71,1,73,1,74,1,75,1,64,2,67,2,69,2,70,
    2,72,2,74,2,60,3,63,3,65,3,67,3,69,3,71,3,72,3,73,3,75,3,76,3,57,4,62,4,66,4,68,4,70,4,72,4,74,4,75,4,60,
    5,63,5,65,5,67,5,69,5,70,5,71,5,73,5,74,5,76,5,77,5,62,6,64,6,66,6,68,6,70,6,72,6,73,6,75,6,76,6,59,7,61,
    7,64,7,67,7,69,7,71,7,72,7,74,7,76,7,77,7,63,8,66,8,68,8,70,8,71,8,73,8,74,8,75,8,77,8,60,9,62,9,64,9,66,
    9,68,9,70,9,72,9,74,9,76,9,77,9,78,9,70,10,72,10,73,10,75,10,76,10,78,10,63,11,67,11,69,11,72,11,74,11,75,
    11,77,11,78,11,65,12,74,12,76,12,78,12,79,12,64,13,67,13,69,13,73,13,75,13,77,13,79,13,62,14,66,14,71,14,
    74,14,75,14,76,14,77,14,78,14,65,15,69,15,73,15,75,15,77,15,79,15,81,15,59,16,62,16,64,16,66,16,68,16,72,
    16,74,16,76,16,77,16,78,16,61,17,64,17,66,17,69,17,71,17,73,17,75,17,76,17,78,17,57,18,60,18,62,18,64,18,
    66,18,68,18,71,18,73,18,75,18,77,18,78,18,80,18,59,19,61,19,63,19,65,19,68,19,70,19,71,19,73,19,75,19,77,
    19,58,20,60,20,62,20,64,20,66,20,68,20,70,20,72,20,74,20,76,20,78,20,79,20,57,21,59,21,61,21,63,21,65,21,
    68,21,70,21,72,21,73,21,75,21,77,21,78,21,55,22,59,22,61,22,63,22,66,22,70,22,78,22,57,23,59,23,61,23,62,
    23,64,23,67,23,69,23,72,23,74,23,77,23,78,23,79,23,55,24,58,24,63,24,79,24,57,25,60,25,63,25,65,25,69,25,
    78,25,79,25,56,26,62,26,64,26,67,26,79,26,64,27,65,27,79,27,80,27,54,28,65,28,66,28,80,28,65,29,66,29,80,
    29,81,29,66,30,80,30,82,30,64,31,66,31,67,31,81,31,82,31,66,32,68,32,82,32,83,32,65,33,67,33,83,33,84,33,
    63,34,66,34,67,34,68,34,84,34,66,35,84,35,85,35,65,36,67,36,68,36,88,38,90,39,92,41,94,41,94,42,96,42,67,
    43,95,43,63,44,68,44,96,44,98,44,65,45,67,45,98,45,100,45,69,46,63,47,65,47,67,47,101,47,54,48,68,48,70,
    48,74,48,103,48,57,49,60,49,63,49,65,49,67,49,105,49,61,50,66,50,69,50,71,50,106,50,107,50,56,51,59,51,63,
    51,65,51,68,51,76,51,108,51,61,52,63,52,66,52,69,52,71,52,73,52,109,52,110,52,57,53,60,53,65,53,67,53,70,
    53,110,53,111,53,61,54,63,54,65,54,68,54,72,54,75,54,110,54,111,54,58,55,64,55,67,55,69,55,71,55,73,55,
    111,55,112,55,63,56,65,56,67,56,70,56,74,56,112,56,62,57,66,57,69,57,71,57,73,57,77,57,112,57,113,57,65,
    58,68,58,72,58,75,58,108,58,112,58,64,59,67,59,69,59,71,59,74,59,110,59,112,59,113,59,62,60,66,60,70,60,
    73,60,77,60,112,60,69,61,72,61,75,61,106,61,111,61,64,62,66,62,68,62,70,62,72,62,74,62,77,62,103,62,105,
    62,108,62,110,62,111,62,75,63,102,63,110,63,70,64,72,64,74,64,78,64,101,64,76,65,100,65,108,65,109,65,70,
    66,72,66,74,66,78,66,99,66,108,66,76,67,79,67,99,67,107,67,71,68,75,68,98,68,106,68,107,68,73,69,78,69,98,
    69,105,69,76,70,82,70,97,70,102,70,104,70,70,71,79,71,96,71,103,71,72,72,75,72,102,72,103,72,77,73,80,73,
    96,73,102,73,84,74,102,74,103,74,74,75,81,75,103,75,104,75,76,76,79,76,104,76,83,77,103,77,104,77,73,78,
    102,78,104,78,105,78,79,79,105,79,88,80,92,80,95,80,101,80,104,80,106,80,84,81,98,81,105,81,107,81,108,
    81,103,82,107,82,109,82,86,83,90,83,95,83,101,83,108,83,109,83,110,83,92,84,105,84,108,84,110,84,111,84,
    97,85,107,85,109,85,110,85,72,86,89,86,107,86,109,86,110,86,74,87,93,87,99,87,107,87,108,87,110,87,106,
    88,107,88,109,88,80,89,105,89,106,89,108,89,109,89,105,90,107,90,109,90,104,91,106,91,107,91,108,91,109,
    91,103,92,104,92,106,92,107,92,102,93,103,93,105,93,102,94,104,94,102,95,100,96,103,96,80,97,101,97,102,
    97,95,98,104,98,97,99,99,99,106,99,108,99,109,99,94,100,101,100,105,100,106,100,108,100,110,100,97,101,
    103,101,105,101,107,101,108,101,110,101,111,101,107,102,109,102,110,102,111,102,94,103,102,103,109,103,
    111,103,112,103,107,104,110,104,112,104,113,104,104,105,108,105,110,105,111,105,112,105,111,106,112,106,
    113,106,107,107,110,107,112,107,109,108,111,108,112,108,108,109,110,109,111,109,102,110,105,110,107,110,
    109,110,104,111,107,111,101,112,106,112,107,112,84,113,95,113,103,113,105,113,106,113,97,114,102,114,105,
    114,107,114,99,115,104,115,105,115,106,115,102,116,105,116,107,116,97,117,103,117,105,117,107,117,100,
    118,104,118,106,118,107,118,108,118,103,119,106,119,108,119,102,120,104,120,105,120,107,120,108,120,109,
    120,107,121,109,121,104,122,106,122,108,122,109,122,110,122,102,123,107,123,109,123,110,123,111,123,106,
    124,109,124,111,124,104,125,107,125,109,125,110,125,111,125,96,126,108,126,110,126,111,126,98,127,106,127,
    109,127,111,127,112,127,102,128,108,128,110,128,111,128,112,128,108,129,110,129,112,129,104,130,109,130,
    110,130,111,130,112,130,106,131,108,131,111,131,109,132,110,132,111,132,112,132,105,133,107,133,109,133,
    111,133,112,133,109,134,111,134,106,135,108,135,109,135,110,135,111,135,105,136,108,136,48,137,60,137,
    100,137,103,137,107,137,109,137,106,138,108,138,109,138,87,139,90,139,102,139,105,139,107,139,70,140,74,
    140,77,140,104,140,106,140,93,141,103,141,80,142,87,142,89,142,91,142,72,143,76,143,82,143,36,145,52,145,
    59,145,64,145,54,146,61,147,58,148,56,149,54,150,39,152,44,152,48,152,53,152,51,153,49,154,42,155,46,155,
    48,156,44,157,47,157,40,158,46,158,44,159,42,160,45,160,38,161,44,161,41,162,43,162,39,164,41,164,43,164,
    42,165,24,166,39,166,41,166,26,167,41,167,40,168,38,169,40,169,35,170,40,170,37,171,39,171,30,172,38,172,
    34,173,36,173,38,173,32,174,37,174,36,175,34,176,37,176,28,177,31,177,35,177,34,178,36,178,32,179,35,179,
    30,180,34,180,33,181,30,182,32,182,33,183,29,184,8,185,32,185,26,186,28,186,23,187,27,188,29,188,25,189,
    29,189,0,190,28,190,2,191,23,191,26,191,28,191,27,192,4,193,23,193,25,193,27,193,26,194,22,195,25,195,24,
    196,23,197,25,197,23,199
  ];
}

Try it online!

Nice result - I not fully understand how it works, but maybe this technique of create image could reduce size of your solution even more

@KamilKiełczewski My compressed data is not the image itself. It contains the tiles and the grid that are used to draw the image pixel per pixel, mimicking the behavior of the VIC-II video chip of the Commodore 64. It may be possible to use image compression on my binary data, but I'd have to explicitly extract the decompressed data and build the image afterwards, so I doubt that would be any shorter.

Canvas doesn't need to be closed, saving 9 bytes.

Bash+lzma, 919 bytes
echo XQAAgAD//////////wAE6AQ0YBVhn3uDlgl0vOXoGCYVOfvHpT5vTV2MemT4s/dNjvCzHeHDP6j/kKuC4TkcE9BofQfjfXbpZUkDZ531aSnN1+ePvhOxIhD8bh1ztcMJ0QJ4vXUQZNQLXC9bnFekyTZ6Pz8acfuIvESitf35KRxJeJgdOuMhhuIZwmwNZtvQJyEJZ7PSpR+MrE1uQWwaRSgyB8zToabiMgvuXTiGZ3eblf5XPAaDp+eRHXVf5QAq0Mu0z1/wLmlRMfx9RnBvYuNDoWzy+Lb4Wstf2LVt+maEJR70dlvk9eOuNcpHrGhAtZf6t4skdYaA5VdLI9JU1zKGAVHSX7SbQGOl/Dz/G0jhDH2Y3/g9UfS8nI6uqGG9fmKfGmY3dskFGCCaz10MR/FqO0esQaw5BRIHhS72bGXV4kBTiAepSG7iUE/JaoxxQKut+kvsRX6NXCOxrBCaMsaW5ChO/2BZvcE9HukOz1MuNxbKNWvB69W6zxH6j25el9zx7q1t95VcQh4F2yITn4Ywkg+O/oCUKt0Sjdit5a79KQZ7QLp4rPhuIqFPzsCysewFLJ4IjAy59ZsWNgsVr5ZzOYGPqraLBjLm7s7ejNFrycwq0hOxuAQQ+L08I19feMD24ZvrXFwSKPa5iwXuTj6MvwGC7mfpL0+8ULKacljdtsTCf4m1U9S4E2wmFWn34VLs2f05I9Sjb2HdyV3vSTY6rGZKWF07Ubl1iu4HsiY9H2KJs71vlzsbd2VadLG5jthd8lnCLokaV8KT4OfR7Jz8efwsEpGzYycSU3tyVXqvuJd8/gWXYlNC3IT4ddXoVOAEl8f5TxDUL7Vc9iNtfA9dzWxmw43Y2Hz/yn2+MKDI5WCL4rQv7Myj/7fAiGU=|base64 -d|lzma -d

Attempt This Online!
With contributions from Neil (exact number of bytes saved unknown)
-16 bytes: the converter encodes whitespace with U+2800 characters, but they are poorly compressed and we can do better by first replacing them with spaces, then running unexpand to convert 8 spaces to a tab.
as you can probably guess, the base64 is a lzma compressed stream, that contains ascii art generated here.
The generator was configured to create a 57 character-wide image, because that's half the image width and braille characters are 2 "pixels" wide.
Modern browsers assume tabs to be 2 spaces wide, unlike terminals which assume 8-wide tabs, therefore the ATO link will look pretty bad. here's a screenshot from my terminal with the default 8:


Just switching to gzip seems to save 124 bytes on the input string plus 2 bytes for gunzip being shorter than tar -zxO. And you can save 2 more bytes by removing the quotes.

@Neil: switching to pure compression is more efficient with lzma, so i did just that. thansk for the tips

Zsh +basenc +lzma, 868 bytes
Tweaking the excellent work of @Themoonisacheese above, using Z85 encoding instead of base64. Saved many bytes, introduced a decoding error. Result looks best on a terminal.Code formatted for readability - wrapped at 400
basenc -d --z85<<<'t(T>P0rr90%nSc0@@rh=1t<H3vv}[0Mi?VC<(^Kd6/(fiR9n/(u5T8u{{oY?J{%v}&LN)U%b:pk&w?>>=$E?j<9=anwK##pO+lXC=dzctZ7W:}5D3z^Bg5)(^e[NaBR59k3Ttt?Ol8JdhHmOL8GCUgYHnH4@Rm(ZnQcQyi].xr&U/QH4qawwcM@!eV^LV(Ji2->l2mDdc]84K!1JU#g7iIQieh6&O0A$Ojo*Co>Ac^cu/.nq^95/xu*]WZq8d#%mSroP<3PIR]7YV*tfyp9WqC+LGE4YiC3B52<e$nZn33w?Wu{:0IZiC1FAo<9bHPMygkk*b^QfwJkX3U*jPuu>&s7d4?$Pui]T{YOUbC^xEQX]/w&B[P1SewJ=S{@H[
OgcQTu&{F1RI5]f7%9)!-5?)HZf[IzSjF*:.D=Ok=.3-oyb8@JA^ZkTpQ*Q-*kWlpxaZ8Y$(&M>)(3re&KM*hey4]!W<6s}J2J2M!.c0T.)/$tTxFn*AEr6Ha[=3J@BM[d+$.%/SBnr@v4}$k!qiw{??pHpTl+YVfRSBO^pn-X+hBchvyn6Mub6qKe/TD1#tue=FBJcyST^I^I5)}1q7vwjr[iuC!<4iO9Kr:5?9E:IV@Jzk8^kSG6)pofhGkSVyk/o?l$nsE#gNi!vlfdckym?&zP3}@w=aLQI<O%:ZavbhAE{Kn)2vXqmQ?b)GZ3AjS!c&V+ppzi#-xPt6d3WJ[vUds&8!F8DT!t&oeIOOCWWgee18Kv<.)/DVAbjUEG{D@SOS$q:Pn){&UcJr
nW[C:n5Hx!gXjm{9jB44{^B@x2xRX/Ni.wEzdzd:Ml//&<px9++LiEZ>=Lo'|lzma -d

Attempt this online!

NB When I tried to convert the base64 string to z85, basenc threw this error: basenc: invalid input (length must be multiple of 4 characters). So I changed the last bit from /7fAiGU= to /7fAiGUU= and it worked, despite lzma complaining. This is what the encoding step looked like:
echo {TheMoonIsACheese-base64-string}/7fAiGUU=|base64 -d\
  |basenc --z85 -w0 > waiting.z85


is the decoding error happening because you truncated the stream? nice work?

my base64 was generated with cat file | base64 on almalinux 8 fyi. z85 is the canonical solution to this exact issue (base64 implementations aren't consistent)

But then I would have to figure out your trick with whitespace and lzma, whereas I prefer my strategy of being lazy:)

HTML + JavaScript, 13+1015=1028 bytes
<canvas id=c>

`¾ ¿ Á ¹ Ã »¿ÁÅÇ ¦Ä ½ÁÃÅ §º¿Â ¼ÀÁ ±º¾¿ ¸¼½ ¬´¶ ± ®³¶¹ µ· ­°²´ ª±³ ‘­¯² «®° ¡©¬­ ˜¤¦« ž¨©ª ¢¤¦§ › ¥ ¢¤ ˜Ÿ¡   ›ž  ‰˜œ š ™ ‘ ˜ 0’–  3• 15 7” 3‘    15‰ 246“    9< ",/13468     
7;>‘ !$-/13568:      "#249<> 
!"$+-/1578;      "$,036:> 
.2479;=     
058<>@BGŒ 2479;D    
6:=>@BHV 

479<EN  08;>@BKWŒ 

6:=?DH  
3ACFL   
9<>IŒ   
@BE 
CGLO IYaŽ K  F  !M !"#JQq # S ‹Ž &P VŽ 'S‹ Ž )PT W )*dg +PSbq *,GI~ FUceru ,-DEQ BCWcs -A\`v‰ /@PSadp ?FHIJN]^_agnrtx{€‹ 0>GHJKMR\\]\`equw‰ FKLMNP[\\^biosvxz}‚Œ 1>ENOQTYZ]denqrstux…ˆ‹ 2=DPXY[\\cdpqsvwz|ƒ‡ŠŒ 2CDQRUVWXZ[\\efhknoprtuvxy{}…‰‹ 3:>ABQSTWY[cdeimvwxz~€ƒ‡ˆŠ 4ARSUVXYZ[cfglnxyz{|}‚„…†‡‰Š 456;>?STUVWdefhikmz{}~€‚„‡ 567=>Tefgijlm{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ 789:;<ghijkl€‚„… 9;hj`.split` `.map((a,x)=>[...a].map(y=>c.fillRect(x,y.charCodeAt(),1,1)),c.height=199,c=c.getContext`2d`)

Try it on Codepen

"...girl's face BEFORE what she is waiting for happens"

Why isn't this a Stack Snippet?

@Neil, because SE, as usual, was stripping out a couple of the unprintables.

CSS, 928 925 bytes
This answer based on jdt answer  (I use his image url)


*{content:url(data:image/webp;base64,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




JavaScript, 945 938 bytes
Here I again use image url from jdt answer, and it allows me to actually beat current JS record (989 bytes by Arnauld)


document.write("<img src=data:image/webp;base64,UklGRpICAABXRUJQVlA4TIUCAAAvccAxAA8w7qM+Z/MfeKCk7Z8iSfkiKqrJyrHAHXIcd9f/uKxwt6U77Cxw2I3uXU/RR8Bt5brmBv3k78fcIKL/E8DofVPk4z8t1Xhuqu04cb62/oEl2o5/b9LiwfO1S47fqLVvrtLuefAtjXhca5e8pJG/MS49ocVHb2usOJGlrWe+hTwcfky7b+/zSTr21WXIDzz4rXbivhekdmxjSDx/6R9S+4gmsWvFvLZu1jQmLSnBHBLMMdEKU20Jc9oZLNZ6zpHaBVSJwjXaeZz05BTHvseJpHTQEFsFpgI9cIYyoLceGMaCewq0MXb1AHlsOLRg8djnp1Wgju07lIFnxk7bDjA/tu+0mVaOZ6Clkba9AIzFoRULJiOcNgNqGjtegJiMxMYVAGmEYQZ8xPiDq6F9JdBBhBCbYECtUK8RYhN0VWAHdJ3QOiiLBdZDyUotrE9CNHgfdQbz0pBYJ1GZl0qmJWUHINHRpAwxURqQFdg5TKVKOU+CdokUHw2vSlS+0sjPKomMVBi6R5SFV0gJbpKAy5w7jbbEmM9GJAdzh5Z4RqORNPobtBge0vjgJ4O/tYh9SYKtE+PLZLSJsTUZ+5wv0OMyg5kxLJZqa3MSrO+N7hQjeuMDp15otDOMuN3gEuctI/42OOT8Y6QvjHIoafGFwT3OL84ezJ+TccLZh/mfc9pIqgt2XDIyeoPUSvRCrAKmAjA05Pd75FML/3eldkmBwB2c4iQjOJmtLtegc7KxETcZOzDXOdVZZUQ16B239QZFSy1rBQOSEU7n7EOPMHjAWe5UZ5WxozM4w5kZUQyyEckgGwNygiTBGegN9xJnhZSgSoV2hgR0UqX1ElCMyAbJaNmwmwYA")



